# Send Throttling + Wait Activities in Automation Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, send-definition, wait-element

I'm creating an automation that has user-initiated sends and wait activities. After the first user-initiated send at 9am, there is a wait activity for 24 hours, then another user-initiated send, then another wait activity for 24 hours, etc. I want each email to be sent at 9am each day.

My question is - if my user-initiated sends use send throttling, does the wait activity begin after the user-initiated send completes the throttled sending, or does the wait activity begin after the user-initiated send kicks off?

Is the 24 hour wait activity the correct amount of time to have my emails go out at 9am each day? Or should I adjust the wait time to account for the extra time the emails will take to send because of the send throttling settings.

Thank you!!